# How do you find a url from a input button (web scraping)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm webscraping a asp.net website, and there is a input button that links to a page I need. I'm wondering how I can get the url to the site without using automation like Selenium.

Note: I don't need to scrape the actual page, the url contains all the info I need.

This is the code I used to get to the website but I don't know where to start with scraping the button url:

```
select_session_url = 'http://alisondb.legislature.state.al.us/Alison/SelectSession.aspx'
session = requests.Session()

  session_payload = {"__EVENTTARGET":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvSessions", "__EVENTARGUMENT": "$3"}
    
    session.post(select_session_url, session_payload, headers)


senate_payload = {"__EVENTTARGET":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSenate", "__EVENTARGUMENT": "Senate"}
    


session.post('http://alisondb.legislature.state.al.us/Alison/SessPrefiledBills.aspx', senate_payload, headers)

page = session.get('http://alisondb.legislature.state.al.us/Alison/SESSBillsList.aspx?SELECTEDDAY=1:2019-03-05&BODY=1753&READINGTYPE=R1&READINGCODE=B&PREFILED=Y')
        member_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
        member = member_soup.find_all('input', value='Jones')
```

The html for the button is below:

```
<input type="button" value="Jones" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvBills','SponsorName$47')" style="background-color:Transparent;border-color:Silver;border-style:Outset;font-size:Small;height:30px;width:100px;">
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks - Some of your written code would be great, to show your effort.

Comment: @HedgeHog Done, let me know if I can add any thing else

Comment: `select_session_url` is not defined - What is it?

Comment: sorry I added it now

Answer (score 1):

### How to find the inputs `onclick`?

You were close by but should replace your line with:

```
member_soup.find('input', {"value" : "Jones"})['onclick']
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
select_session_url = 'http://alisondb.legislature.state.al.us/Alison/SelectSession.aspx'
session = requests.Session()

session_payload = {"__EVENTTARGET":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvSessions", "__EVENTARGUMENT": "$3"}
session.post(select_session_url, session_payload, headers)


senate_payload = {"__EVENTTARGET":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSenate", "__EVENTARGUMENT": "Senate"}
session.post('http://alisondb.legislature.state.al.us/Alison/SessPrefiledBills.aspx', senate_payload, headers)

page = session.get('http://alisondb.legislature.state.al.us/Alison/SESSBillsList.aspx?SELECTEDDAY=1:2019-03-05&BODY=1753&READINGTYPE=R1&READINGCODE=B&PREFILED=Y')

member_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

member = member_soup.find('input', {"value" : "Jones"})['onclick']
member
```

**Output**

> "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvBills','SponsorName$39')"

---

### Edit

You may interested how to start with selenium ...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('http://alisondb.legislature.state.al.us/Alison/SelectSession.aspx')

sleep(0.9)
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Regular Session 2019').click()

sleep(0.9)
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Prefiled Bills').click()

sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="Senate"]').click()

sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="Jones"]').click()

sleep(2)
print(browser.current_url)

browser.close()
```

**Output**

```
http://alisondb.legislature.state.al.us/Alison/Member.aspx?SPONSOR=Jones&amp;BODY=1753&amp;SPONSOR_OID=100453
```

Comment: That gives me the postback arguments, but not the url. Im looking for something like this:http://alisondb.legislature.state.al.us/Alison/Member.aspx?SPONSOR=Chambliss&BODY=1753&SPONSOR_OID=100473

Comment: There is only the `onclick` no `url` in the attributes of the input.

Comment: So it is not possible to get the url then?

Comment: This way just the arguments - Sorry.

Comment: @UnderConfident: Take a look at my edit - This should be the url.